# Diffrence in between "indeed," "obviously," and "of course"

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, british-english

Can someone please tell me what the difference between *indeed*, *obviously*, and *of course* is?

Comment: What did you find out in your research? Where have you looked at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are used for emphasis. Let's say you and I are in a room that is blue and I say "the room is blue." Your response would be:

- "Obviously, the room is blue." - I stated something we both could see
  and you are annoyed by that.
- "Indeed, the room is blue." - You agree with me on the room's color
  or you are surprised by the intensity of the color.
- "Of course, the room is blue." - You know the reason why the room is
  blue or you don't want to be sarcastic and / or make fun of me for
  stating the obvious.